# How can I parse a YouTube Url using XSLT?

Tags: parsing, url, xslt, query-string, c1-cms

I would like to parse a youtube url using XSLT and get only the Video ID from that URL. What's the best way to do this using XSLT?

So, if the url is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadqO3TOvbQ&feature=channel&list=UL

I only want `qadqO3TOvbQ` and put it into an embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qadqO3TOvbQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT/XPath is not best suited to string handling (1.0 especially) but you can achieve what you need by mixing up the `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` functions:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($yt_url, '?v='), '&amp;feature')" />
```

(assumes the YT URL is stored in an XSLT var, `$yt_url`, and that it has its `&` escaped to `&amp;`).

Demo at this [this XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/ZRy0ix)

Comment: Problem is I don't know if it will end in feature... the user will just copy the url and expect it to work. My job is to parse whatever comes. I was thinking between ?v= and &amp; but it may not have the ampersand.

Comment: Okay... totally +1 for xmlplayground... GREAT site. Also, I modified the solution there to ` <xsl:variable name='yt_url' select='concat("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadqO3TOvbQ&amp;","&amp;")' />` to catch proper URLs as well.

Comment: Thanks - I launched it a few weeks back. Spread da word :) Glad you got the result you needed.

Answer (score 4):

**I. This XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
substring-after(tokenize($pUrl, '[?|&amp;]')[starts-with(., 'v=')], 'v=')
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**.

**Alternatively, one can use the slightly shorter:**

```
tokenize(tokenize($pUrl, '[?|&amp;]')[starts-with(., 'v=')], '=')[2]
```

**Here is a complete XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select=
"'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadqO3TOvbQ&amp;feature=channel&amp;list=UL'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:sequence select=
    "tokenize(tokenize($pUrl, '[?|&amp;]')[starts-with(., 'v=')], '=')[2]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
qadqO3TOvbQ
```

---

**II. This XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
 concat
   (substring-before(substring-after(concat($pUrl,'&amp;'),'?v='),'&amp;'),
    substring-before(substring-after(concat($pUrl,'&amp;'),'&amp;v='),'&amp;')
   )
```

**produces the wanted result**.

**Do note**:

Both solutions extract the wanted string even if the query string parameter named `v` isn't the first one or even in the case when it is the last one.

Comment: I love that you provided Xpath 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. I didn't read the whole answer the first time when I saw the xslt 2.0 and tokenize code (which I'm also going to try out)